# Подключение к хабу Selenium через корпоративный прокси

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, browserstack, crossbrowsertesting

При попытке подключиться к хабу Selenium (при помощи Selenium RemoteWebDriver), находящемуся во внешней сети (в Интернете), с рабочего компьютера, находящегося за прокси-сервером, получаю ошибку "`OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error.`", связанную с тем, что рабочий компьютер находится за корпоративным прокси-сервером (squid).

Через прокси-сервер работают браузеры на компьютере, но, например, команды `ping` и `telnet` не работают. Прокси настраивается с помощью скрипта автоматический настройки с адресом вида `http://wpad.domain/wpad.dat`, сам прокси находится по адресу `proxy.domain:80`, авторизация на прокси, как я понимаю, доменная (AD).

Можно ли каким-то образом при создании подключения через RemoteWebDriver указать подключение через прокси-сервер (не для браузера, вызываемого на стороне хаба Selenium, а именно для соединения с самим хабом)?

Подключаться пробовал к сервисам BrowserStack и CrossBrowserTesting, но, по сути, не играет роли, куда я пытаюсь подключиться.

Пример кода (C#):

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
namespace Example
{
    class ExampleClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Настройки подключения к BrowserStack
            DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capability.SetCapability("browserstack.user", "username");
            capability.SetCapability("browserstack.key", "secretkey");
            capability.SetCapability("browser", "IE");
            capability.SetCapability("browser_version", "8.0");
            capability.SetCapability("os", "Windows");
            capability.SetCapability("os_version", "7");
            capability.SetCapability("resolution", "1024x768");
            // Подключение к хабу Selenium (BrowserStack)
            RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub/"), capability, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com/");
            // ... Здесь, собственно, тест
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Добавил данные об ошибке:

```
Result StackTrace:  
    в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
    в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
    в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
    в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   ...
Result Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error.
```

Плюс вместе с сообщением об ошибке выдаёт содержимое веб-страницы ошибки прокси, со следующим текстом:

> При получении URL http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub/
>   произошла следующая ошибка
>
> Доступ к кэшу запрещён.
>
> Извините, Вы не можете запросить
>   http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub/ из этого кэша до тех пор,
>   пока не пройдёте аутентификацию.
>
> Please contact the cache administrator if you have difficulties
>   authenticating yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решилось созданием собственного класса, реализующего интерфейс `ICommandExecutor` из пространства имён `OpenQA.Selenium.Remote`.

За основу класса взял `HttpCommandExecutor` из того же пространства имён, и добавил в него свойство с типом `WebProxy`, а также дополнительный конструктор, в котором можно передать это свойство.

Немного поменял метод `Execute`, добавив проверку на инициализацию прокси и добавление прокси в запрос:

```
public virtual Response Execute(Command commandToExecute)
        {
            if (commandToExecute == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("commandToExecute", "commandToExecute cannot be null");
            }
            CommandInfo info = this.commandInfoRepository.GetCommandInfo(commandToExecute.Name);
            HttpWebRequest request = info.CreateWebRequest(this.remoteServerUri, commandToExecute);
            // Достаточно было добавить вот эту часть:
            if (null != proxy)
            {
                request.Proxy = proxy;
            }
```

И создаю драйвер следующим кодом:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new HttpProxiedCommandExecutor(new Uri("SERVICE_URL"), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), proxy), capability);
```

В общем, всё оказалось значительно проще, чем я думал. Если у кого-то возникнут вопросы - пишите, постараюсь помочь.

Comment: Метод объявлен как virtual, но при этом сам класс объявлен как internal, я немного плаваю в модификаторах доступа, постараюсь сегодня-завтра разобраться с возможностью унаследоваться от `HttpCommandExecutor` и описать здесь более грамотное решение.